# Pass usestate array between sibling components in React

Tags: reactjs, components, use-state

I am building a an app that has a map and side-tabs.

Every time a user clicks on the map a marker appears and the coordinates are stored in a used state array.

I want every time a new marker appears to show it as a list or an accordion item in my side-tabs.

My side-tabs component and my `addmarker` component have the App as a parent.

How can I pass the `usestate` array from my `addmarker` component to my sidebar component every time I click on the map ?

ADD MARKER COMPONENT

```
function AddMarker(callbackFunction){
  const [coord, setPosition] = useState([]);



const map = useMapEvents({
    click: (e) => { 
       
        setPosition([...coord,e.latlng])
        const mark = e

        //console.log(mark)
        //setInfo(`${e.latlng}`)
        
     },
```

SIDE-BAR COMPONENT

```
export default function VerticalTabs() {
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
setValue(newValue);
};

return (
<Box
  sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: 'background.paper', display: 'flex', height: 224 }}
>
  <Tabs
    orientation="vertical"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-label="Vertical tabs"
    sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}
  >
    <Tab label="Waypoints" {...a11yProps(0)} />
    <Tab label="Sorting" {...a11yProps(1)} />
 
  </Tabs>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
   
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
    Sorting
  </TabPanel>

</Box>

 );
}
```

APP.JS

```
function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        
             <Sidetabs/>

            <MapContainer center={[40.44695, -345.23437]} zoom={3}>

           ..............
 
              <AddMarker />
            </MapContainer>
          
    </div>
      )
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html please read this doc.

Comment: Put the state you want to share in the smallest denominator parent (I.E. App.js) and pass it down as props

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, always lifting one step up, helps everytime, i have lifted your state up, and now both children have access to it, https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html
the similar implementation could be look like this,
as both siblings are nothing but children to parent App

```
function App() {

    const [coord, setPosition] = useState([]);

    return (
      <div className="App" >
            <Sidetabs coord={coord} setPosition={setPosition}/>
            <MapContainer center={[40.44695, -345.23437]} zoom={3}>
            <AddMarker coord={coord} setPosition={setPosition}/>
            </MapContainer>
      </div>
      )
}
```

then extract out using props,

```
function AddMarker(props){
   const {coord, setPosition} = props;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right! But in my AddMarker function in the return method when i try to map through coord i get the error that coord is undefined  {coord.map((pos, idx) =>....

Comment: do `coord && coord.map((pos, idx) =>{}` before that  `const [coord, setPosition] = useState([]);` it must be filled write or you passing empty

Comment: Ok thank you it worked with coord && coord.map ! But we is that ?

Comment: only show when have data, not always, so we used &&, if still try to call `.filter()` on undefined it will throw error, so we make sure its not undefined

Comment: @DianaSk would you mind to upvote answer, if its helped you, Thanks keep posting